# django get lazy reference by Model

Tags: django, django-models

To get model from lazy reference, we can do

```py
from django.apps import apps
Article = apps.get_model('articles.Article') 
# app.Model
```

But what about the reverse for it? I mean to get the lazy reference `app.Model` by `Model` class.

```
from articles.models import Article
# something like
print(Article.lazy_reference)
# <str> articles.Article
```

---

> you probably wonder why I do this, I need to tract user initiative and passive actions, there's no `modelfield` in django, hence I store the model reference and pk as indication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ***`meta`*** options,

```py
model_meta = Article._meta

lazy_ref = f"{model_meta.object_name}.{model_meta.app_label}"
```

Comment: awesome cheers, btw it should be `f"{model_meta.app_label}.{model_meta.object_name}"`